# creating a separate column for each condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have few columns in data set

```
   Month   EMP   Gender  Salary  Age
0    Jan  125671      M  231928   32
1    Feb  125672      F   11257   29
2    Mar  125673      F   10158   40
3    Apr  125674      F   55709   34
4    May  125675      F  170638   29
5    Jun  125676      M  469000   32
6    Jul  125677      M   77268   46
7    Aug  125678      M  124861   30
8    Sep  125679      M  205993   36
9    Oct  125680      M  421278   27
10   Nov  125681      F  339934   44
11   Dec  125682      F  296470   46
```

The objective is to create a separate column based on the each condition. Condition are

1) Gender is M and Salary more than 200000
2) Age more than 35 and Salary more than 50000
3) Gender is F and Age is more than 35 and Salary more than 100000

i am aware on how to do it Python using numpy.where statement. Is there a way that we can create a loop which can take care of all the conditions at once?

Comment: i want to create separate column for each of the condition

1) Gender = M & Salary >200000
2) Age >35 & Salary >50000
3) Gender = F & Age > 35 and Salary >100000 . Is there way that we can use loop to generate different columns for each of these conditions?

Comment: Kamesh: You should [edit] your question and put that explanation of what you want _in it_ (not down here in a comment).

Comment: @martineau - i have updated the question. Kindly let me know if any further details needed on this.